# Parse iOS Trouble Dismissing Login View

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having some really, really basic trouble with Parse in my application (iOS) but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's behaving this way.  All I want to do is to dismiss the loginViewController when the user successfully logs in.  I've tried a number of different methods, but the logInController didLogInUser method is never being called, no matter what I do.  The log in still works correctly, but its just not dismissing the views.  I know I'm missing something extremely simple here, but I don't know what it is.  Can anyone give me a hand?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

PFLogInViewController *loginView = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
if ([PFUser currentUser])
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loggedIn" sender:self];
}
else
{
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
}

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I appreciate it in advance as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that after you do this:

```
PFLogInViewController *loginView = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
```

You should add this somewhere:

```
loginView.delegate = self;
```

And make sure in your ViewController.h add

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <PFLoginViewControllerDelegate>
```

Just to clean things up a bit as well, I'd change this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

PFLogInViewController *loginView = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
if ([PFUser currentUser])
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loggedIn" sender:self];
}
else
{
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
}

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

To This:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

if ([PFUser currentUser])
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loggedIn" sender:self];
}
else
{
    PFLogInViewController *loginView = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    loginView.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
}
```

Comment: Yup, forgot to add the delegate.  I knew it was simple.  Thanks!

Comment: @StudioSymposium - :)